# Gecko browser Timeout Alert text edit/remove

Tags: browser, timeout, webbrowser-control, gecko, geckofx

Is it possible to edit the Timeout Alert msg box text when getting a connection timed out? I'm using GeckoFx-45 (WPF)

> The operation timed out when attempting to contact some_url

Thank you

Comment: Is it exception message box? Please add some code and a screenshot of that message box.

Comment: I used the source code from here: http://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/using-the-gecko-web-browser-in-wpf/. The timeout message seems to be a simple dialog box.

Comment: Hi, i am getting the same for Geckofx60.64.60.0.47 in C# WInForm any workaround on the same.